# I need to change format of a date column from D-M-Y to Y-M-D in excel

Tags: excel, date-format

I was trying to import a CSV file to my `phpmyadmin`.  Then my date field had values as `0000-00-00` since both date formats were different. I changed the CSV date-format to the format in the database. I have 5000+ data in my CSV. but only a few dates change to the format I chose. Remaining still in the old format

I went to `Format cells`, selected date, changed to Uk and selected the desired date format. But only a few dates change to the format I chose. Remaining still in the old format

Answer (score 0):

Starting with data like:

[image]

Select the cells you wish to convert and run this:

```
Sub FixDate()
    Dim s As String, d As String, rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim dt As Date

    d = "-"

    For Each cell In Selection
        s = cell.Text
        If InStr(s, d) > 0 Then
            arr = Split(s, d)
            dt = DateSerial(arr(2), arr(1), arr(0))
            cell.Clear
            cell.Value = dt
            cell.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyy"
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

to produce:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can only change the date format in Excel once Excel recognizes the cell contents as dates. If this doesn't happen automatically, you can force it with the Text to columns function. After the dates have been recognized, you can use any date format you like.

Select the column with the unrecognised dates, and go to **Data** tab, click **Text to columns**.
Select **Delimited**, Next, Untick everything, Next, Select **Date** and from the dropdown select the order in which the dates currently are in your column. Hit Finish.
[image: TextToColumns]

In my example dates are in yyyy-dd-mm format.

This is the fastest way I know of in Excel to make it recognize dates in any order.